Impinj: How to write to reserved memory (set Unkillable mode) on Impinj M781 tag using RFID reader?
I am working with the Impinj M781 RFID tag and need to enable the "Unkillable Mode" by setting the Unkillable bit (UK bit) in the reserved memory. The datasheet specifies that this bit is at location 4Ch in the reserved memory and must be set to 1 while in the secured state.
However, I am facing challenges with my current RFID reader's SDK, which allows me to write the access/kill password but does not provide a way to write to specific memory locations or use an offset to directly access the UK bit.
Am I missing something here?
I both checked the sdk doc to see if they have any api to write the reserved memory, but didnt find any. OctaneSdk will not work here since I dont have the Impinj readers.

Even though UHF C1G2 is a standard, the standard stipulate or leave a backdoor for RFID reader manufacturer to have vendor specific functionality, this is a specific Impinj functionality, means only works between Impinj Readers (using Octane SDK) and Impinj tag chips (No all-tag chips have this functionalities).

Thank you. We've worked with our reader vendor to address this issue. They have provided us a modified SDK.
